How can I load from different pages in schenebuilder?
test in window11 scenebuilder 22,23
all error only with bundle loader
root path r
Screen a has a .fxml file in dir root/aa
this file has as pane from Jave Class b
the .fxml file is in dir root/bb
so the instance load from b in screen a -> goes to error - so a ist not shown in screnebuilder
the instance load loades the bundle for b not from root !
in design time i dont activate bundle
